# Search another database with wp_query using new wpdb

Tags: wp-query

I currently have a simple `wp_query` search working on my wordpress site. I now want that same search to look for results in it's own database and another one on same server.

I found that I could use `new wpdb()`and then `$mydb->get_results()` to get the posts. I managed to pull a title of one of the posts but now I want to integrate this into my `wp_query`. Is this even possible? Here is a breakdown of the code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'show_posts' => '10', 
'paged' => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

// Testing the new wpdb instance (RESULT: title echoed out. Working)
$mydb = new wpdb('USR','PSWD','DB','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id = '5509' ");
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
    echo $obj->post_title;
endforeach;
// So now, how do I use my wp_query to get these results too?

// Loop
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box? No

You can do some trickery to try and fool WP_Query into using your new db object but it may have issues with cached objects etc

e.g.

```
global $wpdb;
// backup wpdb
$thedb = $wpdb;

// pretend mydb is actually wpdb
$wpdb = $mydb;

// do stuff

// reset wpdb back
$wpdb = $thedb;
```

However if you're trying to pull in data from another site, I would **strongly** recommend against remote SQL queries, if not for performance reasons but for security reasons.

Have you considered RSS aggregation plugins?

Comment: Hm.. I agree, i'm not keen on remote SQL, but for now i think im trying to find a RAW method and then aim for tidying up later. I want to see how it can be done. It was suggested that having the two searches perform and then use an array_merge.. The mystery continues. I'll check out some RSS agg but I have some further customisation on the posts which could cause it to break down. Thanks for your response.

Comment: For anyone else who was trying this and struggling, I found that after setting $wpdb = $mydb; I also had to set the table prefix for WP_Query to work. $wpdb->prefix('wp_'); in my case.