# Wordpress' work or execution flow manipulating $wpdb

Tags: actions, wpdb, workflow

I have read about overwriting global variable `$wpdb` and connecting to a second database this way ( [Search another database with wp_query using new wpdb](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73715/search-another-database-with-wp-query-using-new-wpdb) ) so one could e.g. use WP_Query on 2nd DB. After that $wpdb is "restored" with $wpdb_backup.

See code below from @Tom J Nowell

```
global $wpdb;
// backup wpdb
$wpdb_backup = $wpdb;

// new db
$newdb = new wpdb($user, $password, $db, $host);

// pretend newdb is actually wpdb
$wpdb = $newdb;

// do stuff

// reset wpdb back
$wpdb = $wpdb_backup;
```

It's a theoretical question, maybe independant of hooks, only focused on execution-flow. Will PHP (or WP engine in general) primary execute and finish this script-part, where `$wpdb`'s parameters are set to 2nd database's connection details and after doing stuff on 2nd DB will it later switch back to old $wpdb ($wpdb_backup) before a second website visitor clicks a post link right before $wpdb is changed (or any other possible action handling DB1) and PHP reacts after $wpdb is changed to $newdb?

If so, in this scenario, WP displays a post from DB2 though the visitor expects (well, it's probably less him - it's WP) the certain Post from DB1. If such a post does not exist in DB2 WP throws an error.

Am I wrong? Thank you for your explanations.

**edit** Is it about priority with hooks?

I know there is `add_action ( 'hook_name', 'your_function_name', [priority], [accepted_args] );` for hook priority.

---

**edit2** Short question: Does WP execute one action after another or does it handle them simultaneously (so that there can be conflicts manipulating $wpdb and after doing some stuff change it back)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question right but you seem to misunderstand a bit how PHP requests are typically executed.

`$wpdb` is not persistent, it belongs to specific page load and only exists while that page load is being performed. Unless your code *always* changes it - independent second (third, etc) page load will have its own instance of database connection.

Same applies to actions - they are executed in the context of specific page load, not in any kind of global persistent way.

Comment: Ok, I get that. but `$wpdb` is a `global` variable, right? So if I set new parameters to $wpdb locally with `$wpdb = new wpdb($user, $password, $db, $host);` in a specific page I am not changing the database connection locally but everywhere (because of `global`)? If an other blog visitor clicks a link and causes an action on DB1 in time with setting $wpdb = $newdb there will be a conflict?

Comment: @chabi you are not, `global` only applies to specific page load, it's not persistent between different page loads.

Comment: first of all thank you for your help. You got me, I am a bit confused. Could you provide some sources for further reading? Or just throw me some keywords for google :-)

Comment: @chabi PHP manual is rather good :) See [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and rest of it.